# What's the preferred way to resize images in tf 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I see two functions for resizing images in TF 2.0, namely:

- tf.keras.backend.resize_images
- tf.image.resize

What is the difference? And which one is recommended?

I am interested specifically in bilinear resizing.

Answer (score 1):

The only differences I found:

tf.keras.backend.resize_images advantages:

- supports different tensor channel orders (see `data_format` argument)

tf.keras.backend.resize_images disadvantages:

- can only upsize, but not downsize (as `height_factor` and `width_factor` must be a positive integer)